# How to retrieve data using a form, which refreshes as you select criteria?

Tags: ms-access

I've been following Microsoft's courses to build a database in Access, but have hit a stumbling block I can't find answers to on Google.

I'm trying to use a form to retrieve data from a table - contact details for people at different companies.  My goal is to use the form to retrieve contact information for one specific person at a time, by first selecting company, then person.

Unfortunately, all my form seems to do is edit the first item in the table - I can't work out how to access other entries, or use it as more of a search tool than an edit tool.

Apologies if this isn't technical enough - I'm a bit lost as to where to find help, and you all seem really knowledgeable.

Comment: Post what you have, we aren't psychic

Comment: Trying to upload a screenshot, but I can't seem to from work.  Basically I have a table of contact details (company name, contact name, email, phonenumber, address) which I've selected and done create>form.  I'm a little lost as to where to go from here (I'm new to Access, have been learning from video tutorials by Microsoft).  I'm using Access 2013.  I'll do my best to answer any more questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term you probably want to look for in your search is "cascading combobox". This setup allows you to pick the company from one drop down, which populates a second drop down with the contacts at that company. Then you could select the specific contact and have it show all of the information for that contact in your form.

[Utter Access](http://www.utteraccess.com) has always been a reliable resource for me, and they have a good [article](http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/Cascading_Combo_Boxes) on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Form, that is not based on any table. Just a simple UNBOUND form, in that form create two ComboBoxes (Drop down boxes) and one Button. For the First one, use the RowSource to be the one that lists all Companies in your table. The Second one should basically have all the People. Then you create a code in the AfterUpdate event of the Company ComboBox. This style of getting data from one ComboBox to another is called Cascading Combo Boxes. Here are a few very good description of the same:

http://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut10.htm
http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/Forms/combo-boxes/cascading.html

Then once you have selected the Name of the Company and Person, you can simply open the Record from the Person table with the corresponding ID on button click by using the DoCmd.OpenForm.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thank you so much!  These links are going to be really handy.  If I could, I'd vote you up!